# ClassCastException with no stacktrace in LineBreakMeasurer

Tags: java, printing, classcastexception

I am trying to print a justified paragraph in a right to left language (Arabic), and trying to achieve that using **TextLayout** and **LineBreakerMeasurer**, since the consensus around the web seems to be that trying to code the calculations for the positions of each word/character is a big waste of time and effort (I have tried it and haven't had much luck).

The issue I encountered is implementing the **AttributedCharacterIterator** correctly. More specifically, I'm getting a **ClassCastException, but without any stacktrace**.

First code snippet is the printing code, taken from the print method of a class implementing Printable:

```
AttributedCharacterIterator it = (AttributedCharacterIterator) new MyCharacterIterator(paragraph);
            int xPos = (int) pf.getImageableX();
            int yPos = (int) pf.getImageableY();

            // EDIT: line causing the exception
            LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(it, frc); 
            float wrappingWidth = (float) pf.getImageableWidth();

            while (measurer.getPosition() < paragraph.length()) {

                 TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);

                 yPos += (layout.getAscent());
                 float dx = layout.isLeftToRight() ?
                     0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());

                     layout.draw((Graphics2D)g, xPos + dx, yPos);
                 yPos += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
            }
```

Second code snippet is the implementation of AttributedCharacterIterator:

```
import java.awt.font.NumericShaper;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyCharacterIterator implements AttributedCharacterIterator {

char[] chars;
int current;

    public MyCharacterIterator(String text) {

        chars = new char[text.length()+1];
        System.out.println(chars.length);
        text.getChars(0, text.length(), chars, 0);
        System.out.println(new String(chars).length());
        current = 0;
    }

    public Object clone() { 
        return null; 
    }

    @Override
    public char current() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return chars[current];
    }

    @Override
    public char first() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current = 0;
        return chars[current];
    }

    @Override
    public int getBeginIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

       @Override
    public int getEndIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return chars.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public char last() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return chars[chars.length-1];
    }

    @Override
    public char next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current += 1;
        if(current<chars.length) {      
            return chars[current];
        }
            else {
            return CharacterIterator.DONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public char previous() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current -=1;
        return chars[current];
    } 

    @Override
    public char setIndex(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current = position;
        return chars[current];
    } 

    @Override
    public Set<Attribute> getAllAttributeKeys() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TreeSet<Attribute> set = new TreeSet<Attribute>();
        set.add(TextAttributeConstants.RUN_DIRECTION);
        set.add(TextAttributeConstants.NUMERIC_SHAPING);
        set.add(TextAttributeConstants.BIDI_EMBEDDING);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(Attribute attribute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(attribute==TextAttributeConstants.RUN_DIRECTION) {
            return false;
        }
        else if(attribute==TextAttributeConstants.NUMERIC_SHAPING) {
            return NumericShaper.getContextualShaper(100);
        }
        else if(attribute==TextAttributeConstants.BIDI_EMBEDDING) {
            return 0;
        }
        else return new Object();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Attribute, Object> getAttributes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TreeMap<Attribute, Object> map = new TreeMap<Attribute, Object>();
        map.clear();
        return map;

    }

    @Override
    public int getRunLimit() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRunLimit(Attribute attribute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

@Override
public int getRunLimit(Set<? extends Attribute> attributes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRunStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRunStart(Attribute attribute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRunStart(Set<? extends Attribute> attributes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private static class TextAttributeConstants {
    private static final Class<?> clazz = getClass("java.awt.font.TextAttribute");

    static final AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute RUN_DIRECTION = getTextAttribute("RUN_DIRECTION");
    static final AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute NUMERIC_SHAPING = getTextAttribute("NUMERIC_SHAPING");
    static final AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute BIDI_EMBEDDING = getTextAttribute("BIDI_EMBEDDING");

    static final Boolean RUN_DIRECTION_LTR = (clazz == null) ? Boolean.FALSE : (Boolean)getStaticField(clazz, "RUN_DIRECTION_LTR");


    private static Class<?> getClass(String name) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(name, true, null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Object getStaticField(Class<?> clazz, String name) {
        try {
            Field f = clazz.getField(name);
            return f.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
    }

    private static AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute
        getTextAttribute(String name)
    {
        if (clazz == null) {
            // fake attribute
            return new AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute(name) { };
        } else {
            return (AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute)getStaticField(clazz, name);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How do you know it is caused by `AttributedCharacterIterator ` if you do not have a stacktrace

Comment: Do more homework.  Make your debugger stop execution when that exception is thrown.

Comment: I know it's caused by the line using the AttributedCharacterIterator instance to construct a LineBreakMeasurer because I did some manual debugging, and because I had a couple of similar exceptions generated before, and I did have a stack trace for those. (I had to go into JRE source code even to follow up on those).

Comment: It's also my first time trying to implement AttributedCharacterIterator.

Comment: I edited a // comment indicating the line causing the exception.

Comment: Does the exception happen in the constructor of `LineBreakMeasurer`, or somewhere deeper? I've looked at the source code of that class, but there isn't anything that looks like there would be any class casting. Is it possible for you to step into that line when debugging?

Comment: I think it's deeper. My guess is that the output of one of the methods from `AttributedCharacterIterator` is being used somewhere deeper and cast to something it's not. The primary suspect given previous exceptions that I managed to avoid seems to be `public Object getAttribute(Attribute attribute) {.....}`. I can't really say for sure though.

Comment: Can someone do me the favor of reading the code for the `MyCharacterIterator` class and see if there are some glaring mistakes or bad choices at least? In the meantime I'm looking into debugging, but the thing is, this hasn't actually worked even once yet, so the more time I spend debugging the more it feels like a fool's errand.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is no need to implement AttributedCharacterIterator at all in this case, as String objects can be converted to AttributedString and the latter can be converted to AttributedCharacterIterator objects.